# How do i stop inner loop after one iteration when looping over two Lists?

Tags: c#, .net

Here's my code:

```
List<int> myValues = new List<int>(new int[] { 5, 9, 3, 4, 7, 12, 0, 15 });
List<int> newOnly = new List<int>(new int[] { 5, 7, 1, 11, 7, 19, 76, 18 });
List<int> newValues = new List<int>();

for (int i = 0; i < myValues.Count; i++){
    for (int x = 0; x < newOnly.Count; x++){
        if (!myValues.Contains(newOnly[x])){
                        newValues.Add(newOnly[x]);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to check if the item in `newOnly` already exists in `myValues` once.  Now in the end I am getting in `newValues` 40 items and I should get only 9.

Comment: To start with....why do you iterate over myValues and not just over newOnly?

Comment: delete and that and use LINQ.

Comment: Look into the `break` keyword: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adbctzc4.aspx

Comment: If you want to use Linq.This might help you. newValues = newOnly.Where(
                x => !myValues.Contains(x)).ToList();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll want to update your if-condition to make sure you are not adding duplicate references to the newValues list:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myValues.Count; i++)
        {

            for (int x = 0; x < newOnly.Count; x++)
            {
                if (!myValues.Contains(newOnly[x]) && !newValues.Contains(newOnly[x]))
                {
                    newValues.Add(newOnly[x]);

                }
            }

        }
```

Of course, this may not be the most efficient method, as you will be iterating over the full `newOnly` list every time regardless.

You might want to do an Except over `newOnly` with `newValues` at each iteration over `myValues` so that you're only iterating over items that aren't already in `newValues`

Answer (score 3):

You don't need your outer for loop since you aren't indexing into `myValues` anywhere.  A simple fix to your current code would be:

```
for (int x = 0; x < newOnly.Count; x++){
    if (!myValues.Contains(newOnly[x]))
        newValues.Add(newOnly[x]);
}
```

There are better solutions - as mentioned in the comments using `LINQ` would be a good choice.

Answer (score 0):

Because others have answered how to fix your code, here is one that answers your question of how to stop the inner loop:

Look into the `break` keyword:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adbctzc4.aspx

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
     for (int x = 0; x < 20; x++)
     {
         if (x == 5)
            break;
     }
}
```

If the `if` condition hits, it will exit out of the inner `for` loop and go back to the outer.